# Compute integral with respect to Lebesgue measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm taking a course on measure theory.

I know that there is the following property: If $F_X(x)$ is continuously differentiable on $[a, b]$, then $\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dF_X(x) = \int_a^b g(x)f_X(x)dx$, where $f_X(x) = F_X'(x)$.

My first question is, in probability theory, $F_X(x)$ is called density. Is the concept applicable to other areas? If not, how do you compute the integral? (I mean, I know there are theorems as the monotone convergence and the dominated convergence, but I'm asking for the cases like the one below).

Let
$F(x) =
\begin{cases}
\begin{align*}
x \ &,x<1 \\
4x^2 \ &, x \geq 1
\end{align*}
\end{cases}$. Compute $\int g \,d\mu_F$, where
$g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{align*}
x+1 \ &, 0 \leq x \leq 2\\
4 \ &, 2 \leq x \leq 3\\
0 \ &, x \notin [0,3]
\end{align*}
\end{cases}
$

What I tried to do was
$$ \begin{align*}
\int g \,d\mu_f &= \int_0^2 g(x) \,dx + g(x)(\mu_F(2)-\lim_{x \to 2} \mu_F(2) + \int_2^3 g(x) \,dx \\
&= \int_0^2 x+1 \,dx + 4(0-0) + \int_2^3 4 \,dx \\
&= \frac{11}{2}
\end{align*}
$$

Is this correct? I'm not very sure, as I said, it is not common to see examples like this in textbooks

Comment: No, $F_X$ is more analogous to the CDF, not the density. And note it's not continuously differentiable here... there is a discontinuity (i.e. an 'atom' in probability terms) at $1.$